# how to update a case details from web to case based on one field value

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, web2lead, case-object

I am capturing details from web to case and creating a case.
I have one field Employee number.if its already in any case and again when the case is getting capture from web ,then case needs to be updated

Because already case with that employeeId is present in the salesforce.
Please suggest.

Comment: could you post the current apex code you tried so far?

Comment: I have not written any apex code.Just wanted to know ..Is this possible to update a case using Web to case and if yes then how could I achieve this.How apex trigger is going to understand from web to lead its a update or insert